# Kotlin Multi Platform framwork CodeSig problem on a Mac OS application

Tags: macos, kotlin-multiplatform

I created a module using kotlin multi-platform and is it is working perfectly on Android and iOS, but when I try to do the same for a macOS app I get the following error:

```
XYZ.app: code object is not signed at all
Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code
```

I'm generating the framework as follow:

```
kotlin {
    jvm("android")

    macosX64("mac") {
        binaries {
            framework {
                baseName = "XyzForMac"
            }
        }
    }

    def iosClosure = {
        binaries {
            framework {
                baseName = "XyzForIos"
            }
        }
    }
    if (System.getenv("SDK_NAME")?.startsWith("iphoneos")) {
        iosArm64("ios", iosClosure)
    } else {
        iosX64("ios", iosClosure)
    }

    sourceSets {…}
}

task packForXcode(type: Sync) {
    def targetDir = new File(buildDir, "xcode-frameworks")
    def mode = System.getenv("CONFIGURATION") ?: "DEBUG"

    def frameworkMac = kotlin.targets.getByName("mac").binaries.getFramework(mode)
    inputs.property("mode", mode)
    dependsOn frameworkMac.linkTask
    from frameworkMac.outputDirectory
    into targetDir

    def frameworkIos = kotlin.targets.getByName("ios").binaries.getFramework(mode)
    inputs.property("mode", mode)
    dependsOn frameworkIos.linkTask
    from frameworkIos.outputDirectory
    into targetDir

    doLast {
        def gradlew = new File(targetDir, "gradlew")
        gradlew.text = """\
            |#!/bin/bash
            |export 'JAVA_HOME=${System.getProperty("java.home")}'
            |cd '${rootProject.rootDir}'
            |./gradlew \$@""".stripMargin().stripIndent()
        gradlew.setExecutable(true)
    }
}

tasks.getByName("build").dependsOn(packForXcode)
```

It looks I'm doing everything correctly, especially because the app is running as expected on Android and iOS. I'm wondering if I missing any mac os specific configuration to make it works…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem changing the approach, instead of using the custom task `packForXcode` and importing manually the framework, I'm using now the [CocoaPods integration](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/native/cocoapods.html), so what I did:

- Using cocoapods, deleting the `packForXcode` task (and the custom steps on Xcode)
- I'm moving the targets to a specific block on gradle build:
- Because I'm using cocoapods there are no different packed binaries anymore

```
kotlin {
    targets { // <-- this is new
        jvm("android")

        macosX64("mac") {
            binaries {
                framework("Xyz") // Removed the ForMac
            }
        }

        def iosClosure = {
            binaries {
                framework("Xyz") // Removed the ForIos
            }
        }
        if (System.getenv("SDK_NAME")?.startsWith("iphoneos")) {
            iosArm64("ios", iosClosure)
        } else {
            iosX64("ios", iosClosure)
        }
    }
    cocoapods {…} // cocoa pods block
    sourceSets {…}
}
```